# How to parse the following data using regex?

Tags: java, regex, csv

I am new to regex and have been trying to parse this. I have a data in csv with single quotation, now I need to separate each of the column data. The data might be:

Desired Result:

```html
Case I :
'happiness,sadness','abc's','another's'

Desired Result:
'happiness,sadness'
'abc's'
'another's'

Case II:
'happiness,sadness    ',     'abc's',  'another's'

Desired Result:
same as above
```

I have been spending too much time on it. If someone could help me that would really be great.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I had tried this. It splits the text but the end single quotes gets stripped out of the data except for the last one.
String.split("\\'[ ]*(,|\\n)");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    String csv = "'happiness,sadness','abc's','another's'";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("('[^\']*?\'|[^,\r\n]*?)([,\r\n]|$)");

    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(csv);
    while (match.find()) {
          System.out.println(match.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
'happiness,sadness'
'abc's'
'another's'
```

Comment: Hi Jaime, I tried the above code and it gives me the output but the starting single quotes get stripped out of the data except for the first one.

Expected:
'happiness, sadness'
'abc's'
'another's'

Result was:
'happiness,sadness'
abc's' <First quote disappeared>
another's' <First quote disappeared>

Comment: Sorry @SaugatDahal, I've updated the regex accordingly. Please, could you try and accept the question if it's valid for you? thx!

Comment: Your code only works for the two cases. I have accepted the answer. I know it is not in the case but how would you handle if there is space within the ' and ,. It gives a different result. For example: 'saugat,happiness'   , 'abc's','another's'

Comment: I think this pattern will work "('[^\']*?\'|[^,\r\n]*?)([ ]*[,\r\n]|$)" correct me if I am mistaken.